# Enterprise Architect: My SQL query to fetch Package/Element based on Tagged Value

Tags: c#, mysql, enterprise-architect

I have to write a query in C# Addin: to fetch Element\Package that has particular value for a specified tagged value.

Something like:

```
String query=SELECT "package" FROM t_package WHERE package.taggedValue="123";
Session.Repository.SQLQuery(query);
```

I have defined a tagged value by name "UUID" and I am setting its value.From my model I want to fetch the particular package or element whose UUID value is 123.

Please guide how can I write this query or is there any other optimized way to do the same.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Add table structure to your post

Comment: @RavinderReddy that is the problem, these are Enterprise Architect tables and we don't know the structure. I only know the t_package contains package where there is no column named taggedValues or pointing to it. I am not sure how the tagged values are stored in EA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the details(element or package)in **t_object** table .Try the below query

```
select t_Object.Name from t_object 
 inner join t_objectproperties on t_object.Object_ID = t_objectproperties.Object_ID
 where t_objectproperties.Property="UUID"
   and t_objectproperties.value="123"
```

Hope it works .!

Comment: You need to first get the package element from the package id, but basically that's it.